# Does anyone know of any performance benchmarks done between the various .Net Frameworks

Tags: .net

What's the performance differences between the frameworks (for the same/equivalent code)?

Comment: Is there a particular area you are looking at, for example reflection is much faster in the later .nets ...

Comment: Good question--I'd love to see a comparison like we often see between browser versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"equivalent code" is tricky... for example, under the bonnet and out of sight, code might use things like `Reflection.Emit` / `DynamicMethod` / `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to generate dynamic (but highly optimized) code. These don't work universally (not on CF 2.0, for example).

Even for basic code, the JIT/GC may work very differently between platforms and or frameworks (or even on different CPUs / cores). Server GC is different to desktop GC, for example. There are difference between x86 and x64 (different optimizations and costs). So I'm afraid it boils down to specific tests on specific areas. A broad brush "is 20% faster" won't necessarily apply to the CPU-intensive part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

[Mono vs. .NET Performance Test](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128154823/http://geekswithblogs.net/CISCBrain/articles/Mono_vs_dotNet_Performance_Test.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that's what Ash was looking for but I found it interesting.